# How to add a \pagebreak in rmarkdown document

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I need to insert a `\pagebreak` in a PDF file generated from an rmarkdown document. The `\pagebreak` must be inserted by a function. I have been checking the previous related posts here, but none of the suggested solutions work for me. If I use `cat("\\pagebreak")` inside the function and add the chunk option `results="asis"` the pagebreak is not having any effect. If I don't use the `results="asis"`option then the text "## \pagebreak" appears in the document. If I do not use the `results="asis"` option but use `knitr_asisoutput("\\pagebreak")` again I do not observe the pagebreak effect.

Any different suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not clear on the need for the function call. But have you looked at [this](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html#overview)? Latex can be embedded in Rmarkdown

Comment: You can give `\newpage` a try.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. The need for the function call is because the function creates several plots in a loop and I want to insert a \pagebreak after each plot. The \newpage behaves the same than the \pagebreak.